# Performance difference between Scan and Get?

Tags: hbase

I have an HBase table containing `8G` of data.

When I use a partial key scan on that table to retrieve a value for a given key I get almost constant time value retrieval.

When I use a `Get`, the time taken is far greater than with the scan.  However when I looked inside the code, I found that `Get` itself uses a `Scan`.

Can anyone explain this time difference?

Comment: They should at least be equally fast in my opinion. Can you post both your `scan` and `get` query?

Comment: I think you should post your code, and table design, so we can discuss it.

Answer (score 5):

Correct, when you issue a Get, there is a scan happening behind the scenes. [Cloudera's blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-io-hfile-input-output/) confirms this: "Each time a get or a scan is issued, HBase scan (sic) through each file to find the result."

I can't confirm your results, but I think the clue may lie in your "partial key scan". When you compare a partial key scan and a get, remember that the row key you use for Get can be a much longer string than the partial key you use for the scan.

In that case, for the Get, HBase has to do a deterministic lookup to ascertain the exact location of the row key that it needs to match and fetch it. But with the partial key, HBase does not need to lookup the exact key match, and just needs to find the more approximate location of that key prefix.

The answer for this is: it depends. I think it will depend on:

1. Your row key "schema" or composition
2. The length of the Get key and the Scan prefix
3. How many regions you have

and possibly other factors.

Comment: while blog suggests this, but there has to be a difference as get can make use of bloom filter but scans can not right?

Comment: Yes, apparently it is possible to speed up scans using a bloom filter, but I don't know enough about bloom filters to answer this question, hopefully someone else knows.

Answer (score 2):

On the backend HRegion both Scan and Get amount to *nearly* the same thing. They both end up executed by  HRegion.RegionScannerImpl.  Note below that the get() within that class instantiates a RegionScanner - similarly to invoking a Scan.

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.RegionScannerImpl

```
public List<Cell> get(Get get, boolean withCoprocessor)
throws IOException {

List<Cell> results = new ArrayList<Cell>();

// pre-get CP hook
if (withCoprocessor && (coprocessorHost != null)) {
   if (coprocessorHost.preGet(get, results)) {
     return results;
   }
}

Scan scan = new Scan(get);
```

In the case of a get(), only a single row is returned - by invoking scanner.next() one time:

```
RegionScanner scanner = null;
try {
  scanner = getScanner(scan);
  scanner.next(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

While [cloudera document](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/admin_hbase_scanning.html) suggests that Get is scan behind the scene

> Get and Scan are the two ways to read data from HBase, aside from manually parsing HFiles. A Get is simply a Scan limited by the API to one row. A Scan fetches zero or more rows of a table

There is a subtle difference between them, **Get calls can make use of bloom filter and not read few StoreFiles. Bug scans can not use these bloom filters.** Quoted [here](http://devdoc.net/bigdata/hbase-0.98.7-hadoop1/book/perf.schema.html#schema.bloom)

> In terms of HBase, Bloom filters provide a lightweight in-memory structure to reduce the number of disk reads for a given Get operation (Bloom filters do not work with Scans) to only the StoreFiles likely to contain the desired Row. The potential performance gain increases with the number of parallel reads.

Hence it purely depends on use cases. Performance of scan should be less than or equals to Get operations.